# ScrollSpy.js offset in percents

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the data-offset of [ScrollSpy.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) in percents instead of pixels?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can, not without hacking the scrollspy JS file.

I would recommend you calculate the pixels from the percentage scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your want to offset your #header which is heighted in %

then use http://api.jquery.com/height/ on your #header to offset scrollspy